# Extending R's summary function (or creating a new function with similar output) to display factors as percent of total

Tags: r, summary

Is there a way to easily extend R's `summary()` function (or to create a new function with similar output) to display factors as a percent of the total?

```
summary(chickwts)
#     weight             feed   
# Min.   :108.0   casein   :12  
# 1st Qu.:204.5   horsebean:10  
# Median :258.0   linseed  :12  
# Mean   :261.3   meatmeal :11  
# 3rd Qu.:323.5   soybean  :14  
# Max.   :423.0   sunflower:12
```

**Desired output:**

```
pct_summary(chickwts)
#     weight             feed   
# Min.   :108.0   casein   :17%  
# 1st Qu.:204.5   horsebean:14% 
# Median :258.0   linseed  :17% 
# Mean   :261.3   meatmeal :15%  
# 3rd Qu.:323.5   soybean  :20%  
# Max.   :423.0   sunflower:17%  

# Or even this...
#     weight             feed   
# Min.   :108.0   casein   :12 17%  
# 1st Qu.:204.5   horsebean:10 14% 
# Median :258.0   linseed  :12 17% 
# Mean   :261.3   meatmeal :11 15%  
# 3rd Qu.:323.5   soybean  :14 20%  
# Max.   :423.0   sunflower:12 17%
```

The closest thing I have found is `Hmisc::describe()`.

Comment: First of all you have to ask yourself which method of the summary function you want to "expand". If you use `methods(summary)` you'll see that there are quite a lot.

Comment: how about `lapply(chickwts,function(x)prop.table(table(x)))`

Comment: @SabDeM - Noted and understood, but didn't think that level of "detail" was necessary for this question and wanted to apply it to a more general audience. To be more specific, this would be extending `summary.data.frame` in the instance that it encounters `summary.factor` along the way.

Comment: `summary` is generic function. When you call it, it checks the class of the object and then dispatch the proper method or if no one class is found (or no one method for that class) the "default" one is dispatched. You just can't modify it "in a general way". You have to know what you want modify.

Comment: @MichaelChirico Not quite what I'm going after here. That's how I've traditionally attacked the problem - what I'd like to get is the condensed format provided by `summary(<data frame>)` with the convenience of displaying factors as percentages.

Comment: Furthermore, if you do `apply(summary(chickwts), 2, class)` you'll have a surprise. if it was not character it could done with something like `summary(chickwts)[, 2, drop = F] / sum(summary(chickwts)[, 2, drop = F])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can borrow from the existing summary routines and do this a bit less invasively by giving the factors a transient extra class attribute.

```
summary.my.factor<-function(object,...) {
  x<-prop.table(table(object))
  setNames(sprintf("%1.2f%%",100*x),names(x))
}

my.summary<-function(object,...) {
  f<-function(x) if(inherits(x,"factor")) structure(x,class=c("my.factor",class(x))) else x
  summary(as.data.frame(lapply(object,f)),...)
}

my.summary(chickwts)
```

```
     weight             feed       
 Min.   :108.0   casein   :16.90%  
 1st Qu.:204.5   horsebean:14.08%  
 Median :258.0   linseed  :16.90%  
 Mean   :261.3   meatmeal :15.49%  
 3rd Qu.:323.5   soybean  :19.72%  
 Max.   :423.0   sunflower:16.90%
```

I have not bothered to respect any of the options like `digits` in formatting `my.factor`.

Answer (score 3):

You can recode parts of the bodies of functions oddly enough.

```
## Rework a piece of the body
mysummary <- summary.factor
body(mysummary)[[5]] <- quote(
    tbl <- round(table(object)/sum(table(object))*100)
)

summary.factor(chickwts$feed)
#   casein horsebean   linseed  meatmeal   soybean sunflower 
#       12        10        12        11        14        12 
mysummary(chickwts$feed)
#   casein horsebean   linseed  meatmeal   soybean sunflower 
#       17        14        17        15        20        17
```

This might be a more involved solution than you are looking for, but you could do a similar thing for `summary.data.frame` and tell it to use a modified `summary.factor` in your example.

So, it would look like this

```
mysumm <- summary.data.frame
body(mysumm)[[3]] <- quote(
    z <- lapply(X=as.list(object), FUN=function(x) if (is.factor(x)) mysummary(x) else summary(x))
)
mysumm(chickwts)
#      weight             feed   
#  Min.   :108.0   casein   :17  
#  1st Qu.:204.5   horsebean:14  
#  Median :258.0   linseed  :17  
#  Mean   :261.3   meatmeal :15  
#  3rd Qu.:323.5   soybean  :20  
#  Max.   :423.0   sunflower:17
```

Note: I ignored the other arguments to summary to shorten the code, but you could add those arguments to be passed along the the generic summary method.

Comment: Great - yea, I pulled my initial response after seeing your note. Pretty cool +1 -- although this feels like too much wizardry for my taste, I'll probably keep this technique in my back pocket. Interested to see if others come up with other approaches.

Comment: @JasonAizkalns yea, it's not ideal - it's easy to mess this kind thing up and get weird results.

Answer (score 1):

The bad and dangerous way:

```
# backup original summary.factor
original_summary_factor = base::summary.factor

# our new summary.factor
summary.factor = function(object,maxsum = 100, ...){
    res = original_summary_factor(object = object, maxsum = maxsum, ...)
    pct = round(res/length(object)*100)
    setNames(paste0(res, " ", pct, "%"),names(res))
}

# DANGEROUS CODE. USE IT AT YOUR OWN RISK.
# Here we replace original summary.factor with the new one
unlockBinding("summary.factor", as.environment("package:base"))
assignInNamespace("summary.factor", summary.factor, ns="base", envir=as.environment("package:base"))
assign("summary.factor", summary.factor, as.environment("package:base"))
lockBinding("summary.factor", as.environment("package:base"))

summary(chickwts)
# weight             feed       
# Min.   :108.0   casein   :12 17%  
# 1st Qu.:204.5   horsebean:10 14%  
# Median :258.0   linseed  :12 17%  
# Mean   :261.3   meatmeal :11 15%  
# 3rd Qu.:323.5   soybean  :14 20%  
# Max.   :423.0   sunflower:12 17%
```